# MVC Dropdown name doesn't change

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an ASP.NET MVC partial view but I am trying to change the name otherwise the binding fails

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.RoomTypeID, 
    Model.RoomTypes
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
        { 
            Text = x.Name, 
            Value = x.ID.ToString() 
        }), 
    new 
    { 
        @class = "span12",
        id = "Features_" + Model.GeneratedID + "__RoomTypeID",
        name = "Featurs[" + Model.GeneratedID + "].RoomTypeID" 
    })
```

If I run my software and add new items (that uses this partial view) the Guid gets generated as it should EXCEPT name will now be RoomTypeID instead of `Features[guid].RoomTypeID`

If I go and do Inspect element and I edit the name to `Features[guid].RoomTypeID` then the binding works and my list is not null

I Tried to change it to

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Featurs[" + Model.GeneratedID + "].RoomTypeID",
    new SelectList(Model.RoomTypes, "ID", "Name", Model.RoomTypeID),
    "-- New Address --", 
    new { @class = "span12", id = "Features_" + Model.GeneratedID + "__RoomTypeID" })
```

But the binding then also failse

EDIT 1:
Seems that I made a spelling mistake in the second one

Comment: it seems that you have typo when assign name, should it be `Features`, not `Featurs`?

Comment: Yeah just noticed that :) when I looked at my code again

Comment: You might want look at the [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) helper to understand how this is done correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working

```
        @Html.DropDownList("Features[" + Model.GeneratedID + "].RoomTypeID",new SelectList(Model.RoomTypes, "ID", "Name", Model.RoomTypeID),"-- Select Feature --", new { @class = "span12", id = "Features_" + Model.GeneratedID + "__RoomTypeID" })
```